# How do I isolate the reason a wordpress filter is not running?

Tags: filters, the-content, debug

I have a wordpress filter defined in my theme's single.php:

```
  header( 'X-Filter-1: here' );
  add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) use ( $details ) {
    header( 'X-Filter-2: here' );
    /* lots of details removed so I can focus on this problem */
  });
```

My X-Filter-1 debugging header shows up. My X-Filter-2 debugging header does not show up.

If I add an all action:

```
  if (array_key_exists('dbg', $_REQUEST) and preg_match('/trace.actions/', $_REQUEST['dbg'])) {
    $staging_trace_debug_tags = array();
    add_action('all', function ($tag) {
          global $staging_trace_debug_tags;
          if (in_array($tag, $staging_trace_debug_tags)) {
              return;
          }
          echo "<pre class=\"dbg-trace\">$tag</pre>";
          $staging_trace_debug_tags[] = $tag;
    });
  }
```

I can use that to see that the the_content filter is being run. So that much is good.

Has anyone seen this before, where a filter callback instance does not get run?

Are there any stupid things I might be overlooking that could cause this behavior?

How does one isolate a problem of this nature?

Comment: By the time the `the_content` filter runs the headers have already been sent.

Comment: You should check your PHP error logs for warnings, you should be seeing warnings along the lines of "headers already sent"

Answer (score 0):

That turned out to be the issue:

My callback was running, it just was not able to insert headers.

(thanks, both of you)